# Node child_process with ISO-8859-1 in command line

Tags: node.js, shell, child-process

There is a way to exec shell command in nodeJs with **ISO-8859-1**;

It seems that nodeJs always force the UTF-8 when use child_process

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it:

Just create .sh file and covert it into ISO-8859-1 or LATIN1
and execute the file.

Example:

```js
import * as child_process  from 'child_process'
import fs from 'fs'

const execFile = child_process.execFile;

const file_name = `/var/tmp/command.sh`;
//COMMAND IN UTF-8 WILL BE CONVERTED INTO LATIN1 OR ISO-8859-1
fs.writeFile(file_name, "echo 'ééé'", { encoding:'latin1'},()=>{
    fs.chmod(file_name, "777",()=>{
        execFile(file_name, {shell: true, encoding:'latin1'},(error:, stdout, stderr)=>{
            const buffer   = Buffer.from(stdout, 'utf-8');
            const output   = buffer.toString();
            output && fs.unlinkSync(file_name);
  
        })
    })
});
```